# Are there any 2 x 2 matrices A and B that contain real numbers such that $(AB+I_2)^2 = I_2 $ $ $ and that $ AB\neq O_2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Are there any 2 x 2 matrices A and B that contain real numbers such that $(AB+I_2)^2 = I_2 $ $ $ and that $ AB\neq O_2$ ?

( There comes another question after it, which is: )

Are there any 3 x 3 non-invertible matrices A and B that contain real numbers such that $(AB+I_3)^3 = I_3 $ $ $ and that $ AB\neq O_3$ ?

I need some hints to solve these two problems. Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you expands $(AB+I_2)^2=I_2$, you will have $(AB)^2+2AB=0$. Did you try this way?

Comment: Yes, this is where I started from. I'll give it one more try.

Comment: Using the indication given by Matheus Nunes, take B=I and look for a matrix $A$ whose characteristic polynomial is $\lambda^2+2\lambda$. Do you see why ?

Comment: Yes, I have just finished it! Thank you very much, now I moved to the second one.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, the simplest example would be
\begin{align} 
A\,B&=
\left[\begin{matrix} 
-2&0
\\
0&-2
\end{matrix}\right]
\end{align}

and $A,B$ for example,

\begin{align}
A&=
\left[\begin{matrix} 
2&0
\\
1&2
\end{matrix}\right]
,\\
B&=
\left[\begin{matrix} 
-1&0
\\
\tfrac12&-1
\end{matrix}\right]
.
\end{align}

Comment: thank you, it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Try to find $X$ of size $2\times 2$ or $3\times 3$ not equal to identity matrix such that $X^2 = I_2$ or $X^{3} = I_3$. (since matrix is a linear transformation, then maybe some rotations?)

If there is such $X$ then we want to solve $I + AB = X$, but it is easy: set $B = I$ and $A = X - I$.

Comment: Thank you, I hope I will get around to it this way!